# How do I reliably expose MacPorts dovecot to the LAN?

Tags: firewall, macos

I am currently making an attempt to run various ports on macOS Sonoma (mail server stuff, like `postfix`, `dovecot`, installed by MacPorts) and I am running into a problem.

From inside the machine itself, everything is fine. I can connect to the ports using `nc`

But from another machine on my LAN I cannot. It simply times out when I try

```
nc -v -z <sonoma-machine-ip> 993
```

from any other machine on the LAN. But on the machine itself it works. The process is running, it is listening to the correct port.

I have used Murus (PF configurator/logger) to see that the connection from the outside is actually made. It is, I can let PF pass it on, log that, and it gets passed on. But the service still isn't  reached. I tried Vallum (ALF configurator) to see what I could do/see, that did not help either.

At one point I had postfix reacting to connections from outside the Mac, but not dovecot. Then I tried to change everything back and try again, now postfix isn't accepting connections either and I don't remember what I exactly did (a combination of turning the firewall on, adding binaries to 'allowed' in combination with PF/ALF settings, rebooting).

Two questions:

1. how do I reliably expose MacPorts dovecot to the outside?
2. how do I find out what part of Sonoma is stopping the connection and why?

(See comment below for an observation that might be a solution, or not)

Comment: So, here is something weird. I rebooted in recovery, turned SIP off, rebooted, the services are reachable. Then I again rebooted in recovery, turned SIP on, rebooted, and now the services remain reachable. It seems the SIP off/on cycle cleared something. No certainty yet, but it is weird.

Comment: I would bet it's the simple reboot which made dovecot start from fresh and was able to connect to its socket since you modified its status of application allowed to accept incoming connection. SIP is a false saver here :).

Comment: @gctwnl Extra information should be in an edit to the question and not in a comment which could be missed

Comment: Could you confirm that a simple reboot or a restart of dovecot is enough to take into account the socket level firewall configuration, and then make a nice answer to your original question. This might help other users interested in understanding the 2 layers firewalling of macOS, and when they act.

Comment: I did a simple reboot at the time, but the problem only went away after the SIP off/on reboots. I haven't seen the behaviour since so cannot amend.